# Angular 4: reactive form control is stuck in pending state with a custom async validator

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am building an Angular 4 app that requires the BriteVerify email validation on form fields in several components. I am trying to implement this validation as a custom async validator that I can use with reactive forms. Currently, I can get the API response, but the control status is stuck in pending state. I get no errors so I am a bit confused. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is my code.

### Component

```js
import { Component, 
         OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, 
         FormGroup, 
         FormControl, 
         Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { EmailValidationService } from '../services/email-validation.service';

import { CustomValidators } from '../utilities/custom-validators/custom-validators';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './email-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./email-form.component.sass']
})

export class EmailFormComponent implements OnInit {

    public emailForm: FormGroup;
    public formSubmitted: Boolean;
    public emailSent: Boolean;
    
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private builder: FormBuilder,
        private service: EmailValidationService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.formSubmitted = false;
        this.emailForm = this.builder.group({
            email: [ '', [ Validators.required ], [ CustomValidators.briteVerifyValidator(this.service) ] ]
        });
    }

    get email() {
        return this.emailForm.get('email');
    }

    // rest of logic
}
```

### Validator class

```js
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { EmailValidationService } from '../../services/email-validation.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

export class CustomValidators {

    static briteVerifyValidator(service: EmailValidationService) {
        return (control: AbstractControl) => {
            if (!control.valueChanges) {
                return Observable.of(null);
            } else {
                return control.valueChanges
                    .debounceTime(1000)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .switchMap(value => service.validateEmail(value))
                    .map(data => {
                        return data.status === 'invalid' ? { invalid: true } : null;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,
         HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

interface EmailValidationResponse {
    address: string,
    account: string,
    domain: string,
    status: string,
    connected: string,
    disposable: boolean,
    role_address: boolean,
    error_code?: string,
    error?: string,
    duration: number
}

@Injectable()
export class EmailValidationService {

    public emailValidationUrl = 'https://briteverifyendpoint.com';

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    validateEmail(value) {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('address', value);
        return this.http.get<EmailValidationResponse>(this.emailValidationUrl, {
            params: params
        });
    }
}
```

### Template (just form)

```html
<form class="email-form" [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="sendEmail()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <fieldset class="form-group required" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': email.invalid && formSubmitted }">
                <div>{{ email.status }}</div>
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email" formControlName="email">
                <ng-container *ngIf="email.invalid && formSubmitted">
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Please enter valid email address.
                </ng-container>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to subscribe to the statusChanges event of your form and see if it is always in the pending status or after sometime it changes it status to VALID or INVALID or whatever.

Comment: The form status is also stuck in pending state.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why this is happening is because I am using `switchcMap()` operator. I know it replaces the current observable with a new one. I have tried to subscribe to the output of the `switchMap()` and return a new observable from within the subscribe statement, but that did not work. It fails with type error saying it expected the validator function to return observable or promise.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's a **[gotcha](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-forms-create-async-validator-directive-dd3fd026cb45)**!

That is, your observable never completes...

> This is happening because the observable never completes, so Angular does not know when to change the form status. So remember your observable must to complete.
>
> You can accomplish this in many ways, for example, you can call the `first()` method, or if you are creating your own observable, you can call the complete method on the observer.

So you can use `first()`

**UPDATE TO RXJS 6:**

```
briteVerifyValidator(service: Service) {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (!control.valueChanges) {
      return of(null);
    } else {
      return control.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(value => service.getData(value)),
        map(data => {
          return data.status === 'invalid' ? { invalid: true } : null;
        })
      ).pipe(first())
    }
  }
}
```

A slightly modified validator, i.e always returns error: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4pzgm9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

---

**OLD:**

```
.map(data => {
   return data.status === 'invalid' ? { invalid: true } : null;
})
.first();
```

A slightly modified validator, i.e always returns error: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1czeuw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Great, very glad to hear! :) :)

Comment: wish I would have found this before wasting 6hrs.

Comment: first() is not working anymore. Now using pipe, but I got the exact same problem as mentioned here and cant find a fix..

Comment: @xDrago, please recheck my answer, I updated answer for rxjs 6 :)

Comment: Hello, one thing. I'm doing something similar. However, when It enters by the first if condition, my form always returns pending. What should I do? @AJT82

Comment: My issue with first() not working was because the validator never fired. Adding a startWith(undefined) caused the validator to fire.

Answer (score 2):

So what I did was to throw a 404 when the username was not taken and use the subscribe error path to resolve for null, and when I did get a response I resolved with an error. Another way would be to return a data property either filled width the username or empty
through the response object and use that insead of the 404

Ex.

In this example I bind (this) to be able to use my service inside the validator function

An extract of my component class ngOnInit()

```
//signup.component.ts

constructor(
 private authService: AuthServic //this will be included with bind(this)
) {

ngOnInit() {

 this.user = new FormGroup(
   {
    email: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    username: new FormControl(
      "",
      Validators.required,
      CustomUserValidators.usernameUniqueValidator.bind(this) //the whole class
    ),
    password: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
   },
   { updateOn: "blur" });
}
```

An extract from my validator class

```
//user.validator.ts
...

static async usernameUniqueValidator(
   control: FormControl
): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {

 let controlBind = this as any;
 let authService = controlBind.authService as AuthService;  
 //I just added types to be able to get my functions as I type 

 return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (control.value == "") {
    resolve(null);
  } else {
    authService.checkUsername(control.value).subscribe(
      () => {
        resolve({
          usernameExists: {
            valid: false
          }
        });
      },
      () => {
        resolve(null);
      }
    );
  }
});

...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like I needed the resolve in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing it slightly differently and faced the same issue.

Here is my code and the fix in case if someone would need it:

```
  forbiddenNames(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (control.value.toUpperCase() === 'TEST') {
          resolve({'nameIsForbidden': true});
        } else {

          return null;//HERE YOU SHOULD RETURN resolve(null) instead of just null
        }
      }, 1);
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Comment: To be honest with you, I did think of using _setTimeout()_ in my custom validator function, but considered it to be a hack (and not a good one) since we never know how long it takes an asynchronous http call to return the data. Also, you used _setTimeout()_ on what appears to be a synchronous validator. I don't know what exact logic you had to implement, but I guess it worked for you. :)

Comment: @AndreKuzmicheff I made that code only for testing, the purpose of the validator exists only in a context of this particular problem

Comment: I see. In this case, I'd still avoid using _setTimeout()_ for a custom async validator that uses an http service due to varying server response times.

Comment: Hi @alexlz Thanks for posting this, can you do same with observable?

Comment: @Harsimer I guess so, I think you just need to create an observable object instead of a Promise and call next() instead of resolve();

Answer (score 0):

I tries using the `.first()`. technique described by @AT82 but I didn't find it solved the problem.

What I eventually discovered was that the form status was changing but it because I'm using `onPush`, the status change wasn't triggering change detection so nothing was updating in the page.

The solution I ended up going with was:

```
export class EmailFormComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    constructor(
        ...
        private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) {

      ...

      // Subscribe to status changes on the form
      // and use the statusChange to trigger changeDetection
      this.myForm.statusChanges.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged()
      ).subscribe(() => this.changeDetector.markForCheck())
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Component, 
         OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, 
         FormGroup, 
         FormControl, 
         Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { EmailValidationService } from '../services/email-validation.service';

import { CustomValidators } from '../utilities/custom-validators/custom-validators';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './email-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./email-form.component.sass']
})

export class EmailFormComponent implements OnInit {

    public emailForm: FormGroup;
    public formSubmitted: Boolean;
    public emailSent: Boolean;
    
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private builder: FormBuilder,
        private service: EmailValidationService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.formSubmitted = false;
        this.emailForm = this.builder.group({
            email: [ '', [ Validators.required ], [ CustomValidators.briteVerifyValidator(this.service) ] ]
        });
    }

    get email() {
        return this.emailForm.get('email');
    }

    // rest of logic
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was updating value and validity of the form just before saving:

```js
public saveValidated() {
    const fullFormGroup = this.clientProfileFormProviderService.getFullForm();
    fullFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
    updateValueAndValidityRecursively(fullFormGroup);

    if (fullFormGroup.valid) {
      this.saveForm(fullFormGroup);
    } else {
      this.handleInvalidForm(fullFormGroup);
    }
 }
```

My async validator looked like this:

```js
private checkNameUniqueness(currentName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      if (String(control.value) == currentName) {
        return of(null);
      }

      return this.clientProfileApiService.existsClientProfileName(control.value).pipe(
        map(exists => !exists ? null : {nonUnique: true})
      ).pipe(first());
    }
}
```

So what happened under the hood in steps:

1. Update value and validity trigger
2. CheckNameUniqueness method was triggered
3. The request to this.clientProfileApiService.existsClientProfileName was made
4. fullFormGroup.valid was checked and returned false as the state was PENDING
5. The request finished
6. fullFormGroup.status changed it's state into VALID

Changing

```
    return this.clientProfileApiService.existsClientProfileName(control.value).pipe(
        map(exists => !exists ? null : {nonUnique: true})
      ).pipe(first());
```

into

```
    return control.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    (...)
```

wouldn't change anything because we trigger the function every time validation is made. So every time we're subscribing to valueChanges the distinctUntilChanged() wouldn't work because it's a new stream!

In my case we've got a two possible solutions:

1. Caching currentName and checking in the function if it's value has been changed and if not - returns value without calling the API.

```html
private checkNameUniqueness(currentName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      if (String(control.value) == currentName) {
        return of(null);
      }
      
      if (CACHED_NAME_VALUE == String(control.value)) {
        return of(null);
      }

      return this.clientProfileApiService.existsClientProfileName(control.value).pipe(
        switchMap(value => this.clientProfileApiService.existsClientProfileName(control.value)),
        map(exists => !exists ? null : {nonUnique: true})
      ).pipe(first());
    }
  }
```

2. Wrapping handling form validity into status changes stream:

```html
  public saveValidated() {
    const fullFormGroup = this.clientProfileFormProviderService.getFullForm();
    fullFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
    updateValueAndValidityRecursively(fullFormGroup);

    fullFormGroup.statusChanges.pipe(
      startWith(fullFormGroup.status),
      filter(status => status != 'PENDING'),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(val => {
      if (fullFormGroup.valid) {
        this.saveForm(fullFormGroup);
      } else {
        this.handleInvalidForm(fullFormGroup);
      }
    });
  }
```

I went with an option 2 as it's more generic - even without a async validator inside it will work as expected ;)