# Angular - Reactive forms has pending state

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am in a Angular proyect and I am using a reactive form. What I am trying to do is add my own validator. To do this, I need to check if the id exists in the database. For this reason I use an asynchronous validator. In case the id is already being used by another element, then it must return an error. Otherwise, the form will be valid.

This is the validator.

```js
    export class ValidadorOperationId {
      static createValidatorOperationId(name, operationListService: OperationsListService, time: number = 500): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
          return timer(time).pipe(
            switchMap(() => operationListService.getOperationsByUuid(name, control.value)),
            map(res => {
              return res ? { operationIdExist: true } : null
              }
            )
          );
        };
      }
    }
```

And this is how I call to validator in my component.

```js
 this.fb.group({
   value: [this.operationDetails['operationid'], [Validators.required], ValidadorOperationId.createValidatorOperationId(this.nombre,this.operationListService)]
 })
```

The problem is that the control has `status: pending` and I do not know what is wrong.

If you need some more code, just ask me.

Can anyone help me?

- Angular Version: 8.2.14
- Rxjs version: 6.5.3

**UPDATE 22/10/2020**

I have checked that the `status:pending` only appears when the service does not return anything (error 404)

Comment: Shouldn't the async validator also be added within an array? `value: [this.operationDetails['operationid'], [Validators.required], [ValidadorOperationId.createValidatorOperationId(this.nombre,this.operationListService)]]`

Comment: The result is the same. The status continues being pending. @MoxxiManagarm

Comment: Can you maybe create a stackblitz which shows the same behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4: reactive form control is stuck in pending state with a custom async validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655324/angular-4-reactive-form-control-is-stuck-in-pending-state-with-a-custom-async-v)

Comment: I think, in order to work, your observable should complete. Is your `getOperationsByUuid` method complete ? add a `take(1)` after your map operator and see if it resolves.

Comment: Here's an alternative that may help.  A three part series on using ngmodel https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m

Comment: I did a stackblitz demo: And it should works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfpggq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Please review ```getOperationsByUuid``` if it's completed.

Comment: @Akash I have tried to add .pipe(first()) after first pipe but it still doesn't work. Am I doing it right?. It would be something like this: return timer(time).pipe('rest code').pipe(first())

Comment: @QuentinFonck Is there a way for me to complete all the observables and not just the first one?

Comment: @Akash I have change my code like the first answer of your link but when I get error 404, the state is pending

Comment: @Alba well you can complete the entire stream by adding the `take(1)` or the `first()` at the very end of your pipe operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `getOperationsByUuid` return at least an observable or a promise even when you get a 404 error. That might be the reason why it get stuck in pending state because this function doesn't return anything, so your observable doesn't emit.
Notice the tap operator. If this log doesn't get print, that's the reason it stays in pending, because it never resolves.

```js
    export class ValidadorOperationId {
      static createValidatorOperationId(name, operationListService: OperationsListService, time: number = 500): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
          return timer(time).pipe(
            switchMap(() => operationListService.getOperationsByUuid(name, control.value)),
            tap(res => console.log('this should print')),
            map(res => {
              return res ? { operationIdExist: true } : null
              }
            ),
            take(1) // not useful if getOperationsByUuid is an http call (http calls always complete)
          );
        };
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. When my service return 404 error, the message doesn't print. How resolve this? Can you help me? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I have done is adding the catchError operator after map operator and return an observable, but I dont know if this is the best practice.

Comment: Well, I would catch and treat this error in the `getOperationsByUUid()` since it is related to that call. Because If you have any other error in your code other than that 404 error it will return something which can lead to unwanted side effect. Try to solve why you have a 404 error in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To handle `404` or any other http error, you can you RxJS's [catchError](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operator. Below is how your validator will look like -

```js
export class ValidadorOperationId {
      static createValidatorOperationId(name, operationListService: OperationsListService, time: number = 500): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
          return timer(time).pipe(
            switchMap(() => operationListService.getOperationsByUuid(name, control.value)
           .pipe(catchError(err => of(null))), // <-- this is what you need
            map(res => {
              return res ? { operationIdExist: true } : null
              }
            )
          );
        };
      }
    }
```